# How to make notifications larger?

Tags: 16.04, unity, multiple-monitors, fonts, notify-osd

I tried to use osd configuration tool, but font size goes up to 100%. I really need much larger font size on my screen. Two or three times larger at least.

I currently miss all my notifications because I don't notice them because they are so small on upper corner. (and because I use 3 screens so it's usually on wrong screen. That I can configure tho, but size is still problem)

I've changed my font size to 0.85. I use 3 screen. 2x fhd and 1x 1440p in middle as main display.

OS is ubuntu 16.04.3. With unity.